# Where is the PGE list of approved Panels

Tags: electrical-panel

I am upgrading my 100A home panel [outdoor] to 200A. I have city permit and also received upgrade approval from PGE.

I keep reading that there is a '***list***' of *approved* panels - but I read through the entire PGE GreenBook and found no list of approved panels. I asked Google [and Bing] *emphasized text*to no avail. [The PGE Greenbook does list detailed requirements for panels and what they must conform to - but no specific models are listed]

Where can I find this list of Main Service Panels approved by my local utility [PGE]? I plan on going solar in the future so that may influence my panel choice / recommendation. In case it matters my current setup is a combined Meter and Main panel - and I see no benefit from trying to change this. If you have a good suggestion for outdoor suited 200A panel suitable for solar upgrade I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried asking PGE?  Quite sure they do not want you to guess.

Comment: Is this full diy, or are you eventually going to bring in a licensed electrician? If the latter, they’ll prove useful in navigating the various AHJs. (Keep in mind that your permit is with your municipality, and that often introduces complications.)

Answer (score 2):

### PG&E doesn't really provide a list

PG&E doesn't provide a list of approved meter bases; instead (like most utilities west of the Continental Divide), they rely on EUSERC approvals, as well as a few criteria found in Chapter 6 of the *Greenbook*.  So, I'd simply make sure you're filtering for EUSERC-compliant equipment when you're shopping.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get with PG&E on this. Many utilities do not post lists on the internet because these approved panels can and do change frequently and the companies don't want old information out there. Since you've already been in touch with PG&E, getting the information should be easy.